# LWC: Anyone managed to get a Datepicker/calendar JS library to work in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, date-picker

I have tried 3 libraries now
- datepickk: doesn't load
- FullCalendarJS: the main libray loads and works but NO plugin could be loaded so useless
- lightpick: loads but no feature works. Clicking a date doesn't work for instance

Anyone got more luck than I did?

Comment: can you add relevant code?

Comment: Do you have specific error messages in the console? Can you also verify that your libraries load properly in the [locker console](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console) ?

Comment: No error in the console.
Both datepickk and lightpick gets me an: undefined  in the LockerOn column.
But I also get one for the main library of FullCalendar and that loaded fine so I am a bit confused about the results.
Pickaday showed also an undefined.
... the confusion is strong. What sort of results is that supposed to give us? I can't seem to find any explanation

Answer (score 2):

I just grabbed a random datepicker library to test [Pikaday](https://github.com/Pikaday/Pikaday) and did not run into  any issues:

[image]

Upload the zip file to your static resources & create a lwc:

component.html:

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <input type="text" class="date-picker" lwc:dom="manual"></input>
    </div>
</template>
```

make sure you specify lwc:dom="manual"

> When using these libraries in a Lightning web component, add lwc:dom="manual" to any HTML element that you want to manipulate with JavaScript. When the engine sees the directive, it preserves encapsulation.

In your controller (.js file)

make sure you import the static resource:

```
'@salesforce/resourceUrl/_static_resource_name'
```

after your component renders, initilize your scripts by hooking to the `renderedCallback` event :

```
loadScript(this, ResourcesC + '/Pikaday-master/pikaday.js'),
loadStyle(this, ResourcesC + '/Pikaday-master/css/pikaday.css')
```

and Initialize Pikaday:

```
const container = this.template.querySelector('.date-picker');
new Pikaday({ field: container });
```

You probably want to use Promises to sequentially perform the operations (check if initialized, do something after rendering, initialize Pikaday...)

For a complete code structure and sample, you can refer to [Use Third-Party JavaScript Libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_third_party_library)

UPDATE:

> Concerning functionality, you are correct, the calendar seems to
>   flicker and has some oddissh behavior.

Additionally, there are many libraries out there, but it is not clear which ones are supported with locker service or not.

I went ahead and created a LWC that acts as a datepicker which is not dependant on any 3rd party library, you can find in uder my repository [here](https://github.com/gminero/lwcLabs) under lwcCalendar.
[image]

Comment: Yes the library loads.
But it doesn't REALLy work for me. When clicking on the input, the calendar displays briefly and then disappears. If I do a alt+tab twice, it seems to work then.
Did it work perfectly for you?

Comment: I added a link towards my repo - where I created an LWC calendar component in case you are still looking for something